# Change modified classes generated by T4

Tags: t4

I used T4 to generate some entity classes , but I forgot to make them `Serializable`. So is there any solution to use something like `T4` to add a `Serializable` attribute to all my classes ?

Comment: Not an answer but a tip for the future: The Power of T4 only manifests itself when you are constantly regenerating the classes. IE you don't modify the generated code. Then this would be very simple. Just change the template and regenerate. If you need to extend the generated classes use partial classes/methods. If you just generate once T4 degenerates into copy-paste programming with tool support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already modified your generated classes, I think you might find it easier to do with Visual Studio's global replace with a fancy regex to find the classes you need to change. (If that's not possible, it's not hard to write a quick console application to process the files).

Using T4 you *can* control which files are overwritten, for instance using the `Output.PreserveExistingFile` which comes with [T4 Toolbox](http://www.olegsych.com/2012/12/t4-toolbox-for-visual-studio-2012/).

```
<#
  var t = new SampleTemplate();
  t.Output.File = "Sample.cs";
  t.Output.PreserveExistingFile = true;
  t.Render();
#>
```

And then you can delete the specific files you want recreated. But however you determine which files to overwrite, any changes to those files that you've made since last regenerating will be lost. One recommendation is to build your templates as partial classes so that you can put all manual modifications in a separate file (but that doesn't really help you if you've already modified your generated classes).

Answer (score 1):

Are those generated classes partial classes? If so, use another T4 template in order to generate a partial class definition decorated with the Serializable Attribute.

Otherwise you could use the [Visual Studio CodeModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228763%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in order to identify all classes that need this implementation inside another T4 template and then let this T4 template add the code fragments necessary.

If you are using [tangible's T4 Editor](http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/), it comes with a free Template Gallery and as far as I know there is a template called "Add NotifyPropertyChanged" which does pretty much what you are looking for: discovering code classes inside a Solution and making them implement a given interface. You might adapt that one easily and get your desired functionality.

Hope that helps.